# Proofreading the "Five Stack Exchange sites turned ten years old this quarter!" blog post

Tags: bug, blog, spelling

A preface, as a frequent critic of the blog (lest anyone think I'm totally negative on it): this post was good!  I enjoyed reading it and clicking through to the posts on some sites that I don't normally visit.  Props to everyone involved in its creation.

That said, there are some minor issues (typos, mostly) I noticed and thought I'd share:

- *"ColleenV also points out that, “ Interacting"* has an extra space after the quotation mark.
- *"people who use the [e-commerce platform Magento](https://account.magento.com/customer/account/login)."* almost certainly has the wrong link: it's to a mostly blank login page.
- *"As moderator, Amit Bera put it, “ Everyone is connected"* has an extra comma before the quotation mark and an extra space after it.
- *"LShaver said, “ What makes me proud"* has an extra space after the quotation mark.
- *"hand in hand.” It is a 25-year-old community."* has the wrong type of quotation mark (should be an opening quote) and it's in the wrong place (should be after the space).
- *"“If you know developers, you know they are passionate.” Developer engagement is what made this community special. You were talking directly with the source and having deep conversations with the source.”"* has three quotation marks in this quote.  It's unclear which ones are correct (probably the first and last ones?).

Comment: *Please welcome Valued Associate #7215 - Ryan M!*, Ryan will be joining the team as a blog proofreader, feel free to ping him whenever he miss any glaring, or not glaring, typos! :-D

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars *misses

Comment: *Easter Egg found*

Comment: And more problems in the third? E.g., third person singular? I thought they had already employed a copy editor. After all, it is the official blog of a giga USD company.